# Compile error: CS0433 type in conflict with imported type

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Never had this error before. I've read alot about it and I assume it is some references in my soultion that makes the conflicts. But I cant find it. There is no reference that have the name of "WeekOverview".
Only finds it in App_Code folder.

Tried to clean, rebuild, batch and everything. But as I said I think it is a reference. But how will I get the right one?

**Error when i published**

```
CS0433: The type 'WeekOverview' exists in both 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\personalwebb\75767f9d\62ef58be\assembly\dl3\b22616ea\c17e3cb3_f0ddcd01\App_Web_tzf1insv.DLL' and 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\personalwebb\75767f9d\62ef58be\assembly\dl3\26ecbd1c\01966db2_f0ddcd01\App_Code.DLL'
```

**Warning in visual studios**

```
The type 'WeekOverview' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website\ea888009\78e5b795\App_Web_jmrhajtx.5.cs' 
conflicts with the imported type 'WeekOverview' in 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website\ea888009\78e5b795\App_Code.cmrt8ckb.dll'. 
Using the type defined in 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website\ea888009\78e5b795\App_Web_jmrhajtx.5.cs'. c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website\ea888009\78e5b795\App_Web_jmrhajtx.4.**cs
```

**Edit**

My problem were that I had on WeekOverview in App_Code and one .aspx page named WeekOverview. To soulve this I either had to get a namespace around my WeekOverview class. Or change the name on the class.
Both worked and I made a namespace around it!

Comment: Open up the project file of the project, do you see any references to it there?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `Temporary ASP.NET Files` for the project?

Comment: Do you have a web form called WeekOverview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you have a source file in the App_Code special folder, and some in-page code-behind where the same type (`WeekOVervew`) is defined. If these types do different things then they should be named aptly, resolving the error, if these types do the same thing then you should only have one copy, also resolving the error.

Remove or correct the duplicate type.

Answer (score 3):

If this has just come out of nowhere try deleting your temporary asp.net files in the .net framework folder. If it comes back then you have a referencing problem.